# Custom spinner picker date time with day but not have time

Tags: ios, react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-community, react-native-datetimepicker

I have trouble with date time picker with mode datetime, currently i use `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` lib for showing spinner but in iOS i need remove time, only with current day (today, monday, tuesday, ... ) then date.

Anyone has suggest for that. Or this is default of iOS and we cann't modify this.

I have try install another lib like: `react-native-date-picker` but behavior still same.

Thank for reading and feel free to leave a comment.

[Update]

Sorry because image not clear. I mean i want keep: First day, Month and Day. Same as image updated

[image]

Comment: Seems like a quick search leads you to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker which tells you to pass `mode` as `time`: `<RNDateTimePicker mode="time" />`

Comment: I mean, i want keep 3 options first and remove time with 12 : 00 and AM / PM. Same as image bellow
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49482201/203766264-1b7ff080-31c8-4e0a-aadc-f6dbb98f9659.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass prop `mode="date"` like

import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";

```
<DateTimePicker
      date={date}
      onChange={handleDateChanged}
      mode="date"
    />
```

Comment: I mean, i want keep 3 options first and remove time with 12 : 00 and AM / PM. Same as image bellow
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49482201/203766264-1b7ff080-31c8-4e0a-aadc-f6dbb98f9659.png

Answer (score 0):

You can easily done with:

```
<DateTimePicker
  display="spinner"
  mode="date"
  ...
/>
```

it looks like:
[image]